# What will cell phones become in 100 years?

Tags: technology, technological-development, near-future, communication

There isn't much more to this one than the title. Think real-world future, no dramatic apocalyptic/world changing events. The "100" figure is more a ballpark than a specific number.

Consider:

An example that comes to my mind is the show Fringe. In it, there is a parallel universe that is significantly more technologically advanced than this one. Their common communication devices resemble earrings. These work well for the purpose of the show, where they're all FBI-type agents making urgent phone calls about the bizarre corpse they just found, but in normal life, there's a problem: you can't look at your friends' selfies on an earring. It might also have problems delivering quality audio for when you want to listen to music... (stereo? one earring?) the point being we don't just use phones for phoning people.

There are some interesting technologies on the horizon. Flexible screens, 'smart' clothing, maybe holographic projection... smart watches are trying to be a thing... but often there is a disconnect between what we think is going to happen next with technology, and what ends up having market success and actually becoming mainstream. I'm looking for the practical answer here: what is the thing that will meet human needs more effectively than a network-connected 4- or 5-inch touch screen?

Comment: This seems interesting, but very broad, and I'm skeptical if it is "on topic"

Answer (score 1):

I predict they won't have a 3.5mm audio jack. :-)
More seriously, I think in 100 years, they will either be sentient personal devices or obsolete, depending on whether humanity opts for machines-as-assistants or cybernetic upgrades. I definitely do not think there will be any tool for doing communication, a la Star Trek, unless we get severely set backwards on our current tech curve.

Slightly more near term, you may find this analysis interesting: http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-iphone-7-airpods-master-plan-2016-9
(And before anyone reads the title and writes the article off as Apple apologists, take a look at the thinking about the sci-fi future at the article's ending... that's what's relevant to this question.)